# Creating customized input field

Tags: javascript, angular, input

I have a phone mask directive which masks phone number in us standard. (000) 000-0000
I have made it using regex.

But I want to display input field like this (**_) _**-____ on focus of input field and then I type. How do I make it ?

Comment: Post your code here of what you have tried. Also if possible, post the link by creating working example in https://stackblitz.com ...

Comment: Where have you tried?

Comment: https://angular-tmwana.stackblitz.io

please see here.. i have already done the part... i want the input field to be 
(___) ___-____ when user focuses input field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this library: 
[text-mask](https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask)

You just need to configure your mask in .ts file:

```
 config = {
    mask:['(', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, ')', ' ', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, '-', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/],
    guide: true,
    showMask: true 
 }
```

Inside your template:

```
<input [textMask]="config" [(ngModel)]="myModel" type="text"/>
```

You can see a working exemple here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scaqhj

Comment: hey thanks... i'm looking for simple solution. i d take this as a last approach...

Comment: can you mark as resolved?

Answer (score 1):

Make `PhoneMaskDirective`

```
   constructor(public ngControl: NgControl) { }

  @HostListener('ngModelChange', ['$event'])
  onModelChange(event) {
    this.onInputChange(event, false);
  }

  @HostListener('keydown.backspace', ['$event'])
  keydownBackspace(event) {
    this.onInputChange(event.target.value, true);
  }


  onInputChange(event, backspace) {
    let newVal = event.replace(/\D/g, '');
    if (backspace && newVal.length <= 6) {
      newVal = newVal.substring(0, newVal.length - 1);
    }
    if (newVal.length === 0) {
      newVal = '';
    } else if (newVal.length <= 3) {
      newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})/, '($1)');
    } else if (newVal.length <= 6) {
      newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})/, '($1) ($2)');
    } else if (newVal.length <= 10) {
      newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/, '($1) ($2)-$3');
    } else {
      newVal = newVal.substring(0, 10);
      newVal = newVal.replace(/^(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/, '($1) ($2)-$3');
    }
    this.ngControl.valueAccessor.writeValue(newVal);
  }
```

Full code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-phone-mask

Comment: hey man thank you... angular-tmwana.stackblitz.io please see here.. i have already done the part... i want the input field to be (___) ___-____ when user focuses input field...